# load a page INCLUDING its flash movie, and displaying it when ready?

Tags: jquery, html, flash, preloading

i have a website, in which there is a lightbox style iframe popup, which contains a flash clip.

right now, the lightbox come up as a popup on the website, and then the flash loads [with a nice loader].

the thing is, i want to see if its possible to load this entire page in the bg, and only pop it up when the flash is fully loaded..

what say you?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function in the parent frame that just shows the iframe/lightbox...

```
function showFlashIframe() {
  $("#lightbox,iframe").show();
}
```

Set an onload handler to your iframe that calls the aforementioned function. This event shouldn't fire until the entire window is loaded...

```
$("iframe").load(function() {
  top.showFlashIframe();
}
```

Set the URL of the iframe (which should be hidden at this point) to the page that loads the Flash movie...

```
$("iframe").attr("src", "URL_HERE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get Flash to trigger the popup Javascript function once its loaded using the [ExternalInterface](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)